# ESTA can you review your answers before submitting form?

Tags: esta

When you start filling in the questions on the ESTA, does it let you review your answers to avoid a wrong YES input. I'm worried if it would do an automatic decline if I tapped in yes and it should have been a no.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you will have an opportunity to review all your answers after filling out the form and before submitting it for review.

Additionally, your ESTA application wont actually be processed until you've also supplied the payment details for the $14 processing fee.

Comment: OTOH putting wrong data is always a risk. We tend not to do a complete review later, so we risk to send also the wrong data.  I would recommend to print a copy of questions (for sure it is online), and complete on paper, only the question you can answer now. Repeating after getting data and clarification. When you have all answers, you can safely go online.

Comment: That's great, hate doing forms!